# ValueError: cannot mmap an empty file on mmap's dtype as str

Tags: python, numpy

i got **ValueError: cannot mmap an empty file**  when dtype='str'

```
 import numpy as np
data=[[i for i in range(2)] for i in range(10)]

fpath=np.memmap('testmemmap22',dtype='str',mode='w+',shape=(10,2))
fpath[:]=data[:]
print(fpath)
```

Comment: This just happens when dtype='str'?

Comment: Try a string dtype like 'U20', one with nonzero length.